# Prove for Rice’s Theorem(Is the reduction used ? )

Tags: computability

I was reading formal proof of Rice theorem in wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem#Formal_proof

I want to know is what we used here is the reduction algorithm : we reduce the Halt problem language to the semantic problem language?

Thank you so much

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding what you are asking.  Can you rephrase?  Can you [edit] the question and add an explanation of your current understanding?

Comment: This sentence in Wikipedia seems quite explicit: "we assume that there is a non-trivial property that is decided by an algorithm, and then show that it follows that we can decide the halting problem, which is not possible, and therefore a contradiction".  What is the issue you are having?

Comment: From the explicit sentence, I believe that we used that notion  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(complexity) I am right?